# Fill a webform on a webpage using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

There is a form on a webpage. It has 2 textboxes and a button. My ASP.NET application when run, should go to this webpage, fill the textboxes and press the button automatically. The webpage received after the button is pressed should be displayed.
Please help!

Comment: If you know what you want to fill and then press the button, then why do you need this form? you can directly load the next page with the result.

Comment: I'm trying to log in to a cloud server. So the URL of the resultant page is the same as the login page.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have an event to receive the data on webform2, either by using session, viewstate, or querystring. Now use a condition to make sure the values are same with what you are expecting.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
//Process your data
End Sub
```

On Page_load of webform2, after receiving the values and processing them, you can click the button by calling the button click event, e.g.

```
Button1_Click(Me, e)
```

This will trigger the button click

Now, still based on the condition you should specify

```
Response.Redirect("PageName")
```

This should help

Comment: I didnt understand what you said. Could you please elaborate?

How will my asp.net application populate the fields(textboxes) on the website?
It is a jsp page.

Comment: first you should send the data from the first page to the second, after doing this, accept the values as shown in page_load above. When values are processed, use the response.redirect("first_page.aspx") to navigate the user to the first page again.